# C3l4Thl_0r1F5dnv_l}{035 - что за способ шифрования?

Tags: криптография

Есть зашифрованная строка: C3l4Thl_0r1F5dnv_l}{035 
Можете помочь, что за шифрование используется?
Понимаю, что вроде идет посимвольное смещение, но закономерность не могу уловить

P.S. формат флага CTF{flag}

Comment: задача из мероприятия CTF?

Comment: да, так и есть.